# Mudar valor NULL no SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Como mudar o valor NULL no sql server para por exemplo 'NONE' , como deixar isso fixo ?

Meu resultado esta vindo assim:

```
Florida United States   NULL    16
Nevada  United States   NULL    17
Nevada  United States   Cell Phone  7
Nevada  United States   Home    2
Nevada  United States   Work    1
Roma    Italia  NULL    131
Roma    Italia  Cell Phone  28
Roma    Italia  Home    4
Roma    Italia  Work    3
Rosário Argentina   NULL    7
São Paulo   Brazil  NULL    7
Yucatán Mexico  NULL    8
```

Gostaria que fosse 'NONE' no lugar de NULL

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Descobri como já...é só usar o ISNULL , por exemplo:

```
ISNULL(cTelephoneType,'NONE')
```

Ai se cTelephoneType for NULL vai trazer 'NONE'.

Answer (score 4):

Daniel, você pode definir o `default value` do campo para `NONE` na tabela do SQL Server.

Assim, todo campo `NULL` será `NONE`.

```
ALTER TABLE SUA_TABELA ADD CONSTRAINT DF_NomeQualquer DEFAULT N'NONE' FOR SUA_COLUNA;
```

Answer (score 4):

Faltou citarem o `COALESCE`

```
SELECT COALESCE(coluna, 'NONE') ...
```

Esta função é standard na linguagem SQL e vale para outros bancos (que a implementarem lógico).

Também é possível utilizar:

```
SELECT COALESCE(coluna1, coluna2, coluna3, 'NONE') ...
```

Assim se a coluna1 for null, pega o valor da coluna2 e assim sucessivamente.

Answer (score 4):

Você tem duas opções para fazer essa alteração.
A primeira seria verificar no seu `Select` se o valor da sua colunar é `NULL` da seguinte forma.

```
Select ISNULL(States ,'NONE') as States from suatabela
```

> o ISNULL verificar se o campo é nulo e altera para o valor passado no segundo parâmetro caso seja verdadeiro.

A segunda forma seria definir os campos da sua tabela com valor   `DEFAULT`, para isso vc teria que fazer em dois passos um seria fazer um `updade` nos campos e depois altera o campo com o valor `Default`.

**Usando o SQL Server Management Studio**

1. No Pesquisador de Objetos, clique com o botão direito do mouse na tabela com as colunas cuja escala você deseja alterar e clique em Design.
2. Selecione a coluna para a qual você deseja especificar o valor padrão.
3. Na guia Propriedades da Coluna, insira o novo valor padrão na propriedade Valor ou Associação Padrão.

> Observação Para inserir um valor numérico padrão, insira o número.Para
>   um objeto ou função insira seu nome.Para um padrão alfanumérico insira
>   o valor entre aspas simples.

4. No menu Arquivo, clique em Salvar table name

Answer (score 2):

Olá, Daniel.
A modificação é simples, mas não compreendo a sua motivação. O `NULL` não atende seu requisito?
É mais consistente ter esses dados como `NULL` no banco.

Segue um exemplo:

```
`update tabela set coluna = 'NONE' where coluna is NULL;`
```

Corrigindo pro Select:

```
`select t.a,
        t.b, 
        CASE WHEN t.c IS NULL
          THEN 'NONE'
          ELSE t.c END`
from tabela as t
```

Comment: Então mas tem que trazer como NONE no meu SELECT entendeu ? direto sem eu ter que dar um update

Comment: Você quer apenas substituir no select? Agora faz mais sentido. Você podia ter postado o select.

`select t.a,
        t.b, 
        CASE WHEN t.c IS NULL
          THEN 'NONE'
          ELSE t.c END`
from tabela as t